# Why doesn't font size show for SYSTEM_FONT in Font dialog?

Tags: c, winapi

```
#include <windows.h>


LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
    case WM_RBUTTONUP:
        {
            HFONT hFont;
            LOGFONT lf;
            CHOOSEFONT cf = {0};

            hFont = (HFONT)GetStockObject(SYSTEM_FONT);
            GetObject(hFont, sizeof(LOGFONT), &lf);

            cf.Flags = CF_INITTOLOGFONTSTRUCT | CF_SCREENFONTS;
            cf.hwndOwner = hwnd;
            cf.lpLogFont = &lf;
            cf.lStructSize = sizeof(CHOOSEFONT);

            if(ChooseFont(&cf))
            {
            }
        }
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPTSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc = {0};
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG msg;

    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(0, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"MainClass";

    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
        return 0;

    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(0, wc.lpszClassName, L"First", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        50, 30, 400, 200, 0, 0, hInstance, 0);

    if(!hwnd)
        return 0;

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nShowCmd);

    while(GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return (int)msg.wParam;


}
```

The proper font size doesn't show in the edit box of the Size: combo box in Font dialog. This was tested in windows xp sp3. Don't know if this happens in other operating systems. Why doesn't the proper font size show?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SYSTEM_FONT` appears to be a broken constant that Microsoft hasn't used for years, and it points to a font that is not TrueType or OpenType.  `SYSTEM_FONT` and `DEFAULT_GUI_FONT` are very old and almost certainly deprecated; I suggest that you refrain from using them.

From the documentation for [GetStockObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144925(v=vs.85).aspx):

> It is not recommended that you employ this method to obtain the current font used by dialogs and windows. Instead, use the `SystemParametersInfo` function with the `SPI_GETNONCLIENTMETRICS` parameter to retrieve the current font. `SystemParametersInfo` will take into account the current theme and provides font information for captions, menus, and message dialogs.

It also says:

> It is not recommended that you use DEFAULT_GUI_FONT or SYSTEM_FONT to obtain the font used by dialogs and windows.

See also http://weblogs.asp.net/kdente/394499

Comment: DEFAULT_GUI_FONT shows the proper font size. If you replace SYSTEM_FONT with DEFAULT_GUI_FONT in original post, it shows Microsoft Sans Serif normal weight size 8